# Opendkim doesn't sign emails sending from external clients

Tags: freebsd, sendmail, opendkim, digital-signatures

I've setup opendkim with my sendmail and it looks like everything works correctly, but it signs only those messages that sent locally (from webmail client or automatic subscriptions). when I try  to send message using email-client (e.g. The Bat), maillog shows the following

```
Apr 21 11:48:02 d3355 opendkim[57808]: v3L8m2jE059174: [xx.167.249.178] [xx.167.249.178] not internal
Apr 21 11:48:02 d3355 opendkim[57808]: v3L8m2jE059174: not authenticated
Apr 21 11:48:02 d3355 opendkim[57808]: v3L8m2jE059174: no signature data
```

where xx.167.249.178 is my local IP address. If I add it to TrustedHosts, then opendkim starts to sign messages sent from this IP. But is't not a solution of course, I can't add IP addresses each time I send messages from new network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to trust and sign messages from possibly any address.  In this case you can add ranges to the TrustedHosts file, adding 0.0.0.0/0 will accept and sign from all IPs.

Comment: is it safe if I have SMTP authentication enabled? is it normal practice? anybody do this?

Comment: If you are using and requiring SMTP auth then I see no reason why using 0.0.0.0/0 would present any kind of issue.  If you are going to be sending from random networks I don't think you have much choice outside of using a VPN.

Comment: helpful answer thx

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SigningTable` option in your opendkim.conf to select one or more signatures to apply to messages based on the address found in the **`From:`** header field rather than the ip-address of the sender.

Comment: yes, I'm using SigningTahle, currently it contains only one record `*@mydomain.com       hexselector._domainkey.mydomain.com`, but opendkim doesn't takes it to account